# Fastest way to search for a node in a tree in C++

Tags: c++, tree, traversal

```
#ifndef __TREE_H
#define __TREE_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include<string>

// structure of a tree node

struct TreeNode{
        string str;
        TreeNode *parent;
        TreeNode *leftChild;
        TreeNode *nextSibling;

        TreeNode(string str1){
                this->str = str1;
                this->parent = NULL;
                this->leftChild = NULL;
                this->nextSibling = NULL;
        }

};

class Tree{

        TreeNode* root;
        int size;

public:

        Tree();         //constructor

        void insert(string str1);       //insert a node

        string locate(string str1);     //locate a node

        TreeNode *ancestor(string str1, string str2);   //get lowest common ancestor
};


#endif
```

this is a class of a generic tree (not a binary tree). What will be the fastest way to implement the locate function? should i go through all the child first and then the siblings or what?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with files.

Comment: *Tree* is a generic data structure, are you really dealing with a *generic* tree or a *binary search tree*? This changes the domain completely.

Comment: its a generic tree. im searching for a node containing the string not a file

Comment: It completely depends. Are the values ordered in any way? Then you can use that to large chunks. If there is no ordering then you need to search the whole tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tree is unordered there is no algorithm other than brute force testing of all nodes and break out when the element is found (if found). When dealing with trees, recursion is usually the simplest approach. The pseudo algorithm could be something like:

```
find(current_node,value):

if current_node.value == value
   return found
else 
   if find(current_node.left,value) == found
      return found
   else if find(current_node.right,value) == found
      return found
   else
      return not_found
```

Of course, when really implementing this you will need to test for null pointers, and so on. Without any other constraints on the tree, the asymptotic complexity cannot be reduced. You might be able to come with a non-recursive approach or a tail-recursion algorithm (based on the above) that might improve the constant factors, but don't expect a huge improvement there.

Comment: This "If the tree is unordered there is no algorithm other than brute force testing of all nodes and break out when the element is found (if found)." is false.
You can consider random walk or A* algorithms for instance as alternatives for "brute force".

Comment: @Daniel: if there is no order, how do you drive the *best-first* part of `A*`? There is no *best* alternative, either it is on the left or the right and you have not criteria to decide. Randomly walking the tree... well, I would not call that an advantage over *brute force*, I would actually called it unstructured *brute force* in this case. But if you can explain how any of those can improve on the "brute force" approach I am willing to learn

Comment: I haven't said that any method had a better worst-case. I just argued against your "there is only one method". Given that we don't know the data distribution (even unsorted data has distributions) it wouldn't be smart to say that traversing each node is the only solution for the problem.
I would consider twice before pronouncing such a strong conclusion.

Comment: @Daniel: then we are discussing the vocabulary. Assumption being that *unordered* implies somehow unknown distribution, I use the term *brute force* to encompass all three: test all nodes as you cannot drive the search through any heuristic. That is brute-force, whether you do DFS, BFS; whether you go left or right it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If the nodes are ordered, i.e. children are less than this node and siblings are greater than this node, you compare with `str` and, depending on the result, have this node as a result or search down the children or compare with the siblings

```
const TreeNode *TreeNode::locate(const string &str1) const
{
    int c = str.compare(str1);
    if (c == 0)
        return this;

    if (c > 0) {
        if (leftChild)
            return leftChild->locate(str1);

        return 0;
    }

    if (nextSibling)
        return nextSibling->locate(str1);

    return 0;
}
```

and in Tree

```
const TreeNode *Tree::locate(const string &str1) const
{
    return root->locate(str1);
}
```

Comment: In a comment the OP claims that the tree is not ordered.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I cannot find any comment about ordering issues. Where did you see this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try several tree traversal algorithms depending on how your information is distributed among the tree nodes.

BFS, DFS, are some examples.